# Making smooth anchor tag scrolling compatible with scroll snapping

Tags: css, scroll

I am using:

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

to enable smooth scrolling to html anchor tags. I am also enabling vertical scroll snapping using `scroll-snap-type` and `scroll-snap-align` in the css as in the code below. The issue is that I can't get both behaviors to work. To enable scroll snapping I need to set a height on the containing `div`. This seems to disable the smooth scrolling to html anchor tags. You can experiment with this in the snippet below at full screen. If you delete `height: 100vh;` in the snippet below, the page will scroll smoothly to the anchors but it will not scroll snap. If you include it, the page will scroll snap but will jump to the anchors instead of smoothly scrolling.

```css
    html {
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }

    main {
        height: 100vh;
        overflow: scroll;
        scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    }

    section {
        height: 400px;
        scroll-snap-align: start;
    }

    nav {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        color: white;
        width: 100%;
    }

    li {
        display: inline-block;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    a:visited {
        color: white;
    }

    .one {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .two {
        background-color: blue;
    }

    .three {
        background-color: grey;
    }

    .four {
        background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#section-2">section 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-3">section 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-4">section 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <main>
        <section id="section-1" class="one">
        </section>
        <section id="section-2" class="two">
        </section>
        <section id="section-3" class="three">
        </section>
        <section id="section-4" class="four">
        </section>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. If you want smooth scrolling to HTML anchor tags without using JS then you can achive this by using `scroll-snap-type`,`scroll behavior`, and `scroll-snap-align` CSS propeties.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/seogca34/1/

```css
main {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: white;
}

.one {
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  background-color: blue;
}

.three {
  background-color: grey;
}

.four {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#section-2">section 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-3">section 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-4">section 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main>
  <section id="section-1" class="one">
  </section>
  <section id="section-2" class="two">
  </section>
  <section id="section-3" class="three">
  </section>
  <section id="section-4" class="four">
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: So the point is that in this scenario, the `scroll-behavior: smooth` declaration goes on the containing `div` not on the `html` selector. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!  What's the exact reason why we  need to put `scroll-snap-type` on the `main`?  Is it that it must always be the parent of the snapping elements?

Comment: I just learned about this thank you I was putting it on the html{} not the section but this worked flawlessly thanks

Answer (score 0):

i use jquery for smooth scroll when click on `a` tag.& remove some css from your code.
maybe this can help

```js
$('nav ul li  a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
        
      var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
      if( target.length ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top-80
      }, 1500);
      }
  });
```

```css
  
  
    main {
        height: 100vh;
    }

    section {
        height: 400px;
    }

    nav {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        color: white;
        width: 100%;
    }

    li {
        display: inline-block;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    a:visited {
        color: white;
    }

    .one {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .two {
        background-color: blue;
    }

    .three {
        background-color: grey;
    }

    .four {
        background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#section-2">section 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-3">section 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-4">section 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <main>
        <section id="section-1" class="one">
        </section>
        <section id="section-2" class="two">
        </section>
        <section id="section-3" class="three">
        </section>
        <section id="section-4" class="four">
        </section>
    </main>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'd rather not use jQuery. I have no need for it otherwise.

Comment: Jus remove "overflow: scroll;" in main class then your smooth scroll work properly with out js

Comment: @SatishModha but then it won't snap for some reason I was doing that before I read this but it would not work properly :)