# Anchor links not working with scroll snapping

Tags: anchor, scroll-snap

I am using the following script to enable scroll snapping:

```
<style>
    .scroll-snap-wrapper {
        overflow: scroll;
        scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
        height: 100vh; /* Fallback for browsers that do not support Custom Properties */
        height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
    }

    .section-waitlist-lp {
        height: 100vh;
        scroll-snap-align: start;
    }
    
    .section-waitlist-lp-last {
        scroll-snap-align: end;
    }
    
    .scroll-snap-wrapper {
        -ms-overflow-style: none;
        scrollbar-width: none;
        }
    
    .scroll-snap-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar { 
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Now an anchor link that I set on one of the buttons …

```
<a id="lp-button-2" href="#buttontarget" class="button-waitlist-lp-secondary w-button" style="display: block;">Find out more</a>
```

… doesn't work anymore, targeting the second section on the page

```
<div id="buttontarget" class="section-waitlist-lp wf-section">
```

I had a look at [this question + answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66433337/making-smooth-anchor-tag-scrolling-compatible-with-scroll-snapping) on here based on [this solution](https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/seogca34/1/), but it didn't work for me. The staging site can be found [here](https://gokarla.webflow.io/waitlist-signup).

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: I have a similar problem, see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75075675/scroll-snap-type-on-html-or-parent)...

Could you maybe post some complete example, including HTML?  I figured out a few things so far, not a complete solution, but maybe I could offer some help here...